# How do I get the "create" button to display?

Tags: remix

I am new to programming in general and solidity in particular. I wish to create a contract on the remix IDE, but can't locate the create button, rather it shows deploy. Here is a screen of the basic code and the problem I am facing. Many thanks for your kind assistance.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: indeed you have to use deploy

Comment: what do you mean by creating? to send it to network or what?

Answer (score 1):

The Remix UI was changed recently. There is no longer a button labeled "create." The "deploy" button is the replacement and does the same thing.